# Error while using cursor : 'Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ;'

Tags: plsql, cursor

I am trying to do a mass updated to all the columns in the below table by using a cursor  & using the sql query mentioned below

But I keep getting an error

> Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ;

```
PERSONID LASTNAME    FIRST     ADDRESS        CITY
11       Erichsen    Skagen    21,Stavanger   Norway 
22       Erichsen1   Skagen    22,Stavanger   Minneapolis 
33       Erichsen2   Skagen    33,Stavanger   Norway
```

Query used:

```
DECLARE 
CURSOR Cursor IS SELECT * FROM Persons;
myVar  Cursor%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
OPEN Cursor;

LOOP

FETCH Cursor INTO myVar;
EXIT WHEN Cursor%NOTFOUND;
UPDATE Persons SET LastName='Name:'||persID WHERE LastName=myVar.LASTNAME and persID=mVar.PersonID ;

END LOOP;

CLOSE Cursor;
END;
```

My Expected Result  is:

```
PERSONID LASTNAME    FIRST     ADDRESS       CITY
11       Name:11     Skagen    21,Stavanger  Norway 
22       Name:22     Skagen    22,Stavanger  Minneapolis 
33       Name:33     Skagen    33,Stavanger  Norway
```

Comment: Why can this not be done as a single UPDATE?

Comment: This cannot be done using single update statement because I need to keep track of the Person ID as it changes  ... and keep updating the last name column with 'Name' string concatenated with Person ID hence I am using the cursor.. Is there a simpler way of doing it ?

Comment: `update persons set LastName = 'Name:'||personID` ?

Comment: Actually .. You are right .. it works .. Awesome.. thanks